# How to create a for loop based on unique user IDs and specific event types

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have two data frames: `users` and `events`.

Both data frames contain a field that links events to users.

How can I create a `for` loop where every user's unique ID is matched against an event of a particular type and then stores the number of occurrences into a new column within users (`users$conversation_started`, `users$conversation_missed`, etc.)?

In short, it is a conditional for loop.

So far I have this but it is wrong:

```
for(i in users$id){
  users$conversation_started <- nrow(event[event$type = "conversation-started"])
}
```

An example of how to do this would be ideal.

The idea is:

```
for(each user)
    find the matching user ID in events
    count the number of event types == "conversation-started"
    assign count value to user$conversation_started
end for
```

**Important note:**

The `type` field can contain one of five values so I will need to be able to effectively filter on each `type` for each associate:

```
> events$type %>% table %>% as.matrix
                           [,1]
conversation-accepted          3120
conversation-already-accepted 19673
conversation-declined            27
conversation-missed             831
conversation-request          23427
```

**Data frames (note that these are reduced versions as confidential information has been removed):**

```
users <- structure(list(`_id` = c("JTuXhdI4Ai", "iGIeCEXyVE", "6XFtOJh0bD", 
"mNN986oQv9", "9NI71KBMX9", "x1jH7t0Cmy"), language = c("en", 
"en", "en", "en", "en", "en"), registering = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, NA), `_created_at` = structure(c(1485995043.131, 
1488898839.838, 1480461193.146, 1481407887.979, 1489942757.189, 
1491311381.916), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    `_updated_at` = structure(c(1521039527.236, 1488898864.834, 
    1527618624.877, 1481407959.116, 1490043838.561, 1491320333.09
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), lastOnlineTimestamp = c(1521039526.90314, 
    NA, 1480461472, 1481407959, 1490043838, NA), isAgent = c(FALSE, 
    NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA), lastAvailableTime = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), available = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), busy = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), joinedTeam = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), timezone = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c("list.1", "list.2", "list.3", "list.4", 
"list.5", "list.6"), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
events <- structure(list(`_id` = c("JKY8ZwkM1S", "CG7Xj8dAsA", "pUkFFxoahy", 
"yJVJ34rUCl", "XxXelkIFh7", "GCOsENVSz6"), expirationTime = structure(c(1527261147.873, 
NA, 1527262121.332, NA, 1527263411.619, 1527263411.619), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), partId = c("d22bfddc-cd51-489f-aec8-5ab9225c0dd5", 
"d22bfddc-cd51-489f-aec8-5ab9225c0dd5", "cf4356da-b63e-4e4d-8e7b-fb63035801d8", 
"cf4356da-b63e-4e4d-8e7b-fb63035801d8", "a720185e-c300-47c0-b30d-64e1f272d482", 
"a720185e-c300-47c0-b30d-64e1f272d482"), type = c("conversation-request", 
"conversation-accepted", "conversation-request", "conversation-accepted", 
"conversation-request", "conversation-request"), `_p_conversation` = c("Conversation$6nSaLeWqs7", 
"Conversation$6nSaLeWqs7", "Conversation$6nSaLeWqs7", "Conversation$6nSaLeWqs7", 
"Conversation$bDuAYSZgen", "Conversation$bDuAYSZgen"), `_p_merchant` = c("Merchant$0A2UYADe5x", 
"Merchant$0A2UYADe5x", "Merchant$0A2UYADe5x", "Merchant$0A2UYADe5x", 
"Merchant$0A2UYADe5x", "Merchant$0A2UYADe5x"), `_p_associate` = c("D9ihQOWrXC", 
"D9ihQOWrXC", "D9ihQOWrXC", "D9ihQOWrXC", "D9ihQOWrXC", "D9ihQOWrXC"
), `_wperm` = list(list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list()), 
    `_rperm` = list("*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*"), `_created_at` = structure(c(1527264657.998, 
    1527264662.043, 1527265661.846, 1527265669.435, 1527266922.056, 
    1527266922.059), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    `_updated_at` = structure(c(1527264657.998, 1527264662.043, 
    1527265661.846, 1527265669.435, 1527266922.056, 1527266922.059
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), read = c(TRUE, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA), data.customerName = c("Shopper 109339", 
    NA, "Shopper 109339", NA, "Shopper 109364", "Shopper 109364"
    ), data.departmentName = c("Personal advisors", NA, "Personal advisors", 
    NA, "Personal advisors", "Personal advisors"), data.recurring = c(FALSE, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE), data.new = c(TRUE, NA, FALSE, 
    NA, TRUE, TRUE), data.missed = c(0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L), 
    data.customerId = c("84uOFRLmLd", "84uOFRLmLd", "84uOFRLmLd", 
    "84uOFRLmLd", "5Dw4iax3Tj", "5Dw4iax3Tj"), data.claimingTime = c(NA, 
    4L, NA, 7L, NA, NA), data.lead = c(NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, 
    NA), data.maxMissed = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), data.associateName = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), data.maxDecline = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), data.goUnavailable = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("list.1", 
"list.2", "list.3", "list.4", "list.5", "list.6"), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**Update: 21st September 2018**

This solution now results in an `NA`-only data frame being produced at the end of the function.  When written to a .csv, this is what I get (naturally, Excel displays `NA`-values as blank values):

[image]

My data source has not changed, nor has my script.

What might be causing this?

My guess is that this is an unforeseen case where there may have been `0` hits for each step has occurred; as such, is there a way to add `0` to those cases where there weren't any hits, rather than `NA`/ blank values?

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Are all `id`s present in the `events` dataframe?

Comment: Yes, all IDs are present.

Comment: Are the IDs numeric?

Comment: No, they are of `character` format: `"JTuXhdI4Ai" "iGIeCEXyVE" "6XFtOJh0bD" "mNN986oQv9" "9NI71KBMX9" "x1jH7t0Cmy"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New solution based on the provided data.

Note: As your data had no overlap in `_id`, I changed the `events$_id` to be the same as in `users`.

Simplified example data:

```
users <- structure(list(`_id` = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L), 
                                                     .Label = c("6XFtOJh0bD", "9NI71KBMX9", "iGIeCEXyVE", 
                                                                           "JTuXhdI4Ai", "mNN986oQv9", "x1jH7t0Cmy"), 
                                                     class = "factor")), .Names = "_id", 
                   row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
events <- structure(list(`_id` = c("JKY8ZwkM1S", "CG7Xj8dAsA", "pUkFFxoahy", 
                                   "yJVJ34rUCl", "XxXelkIFh7", "GCOsENVSz6"), 
                         type = c("conversation-request", "conversation-accepted", 
                                  "conversation-request", "conversation-accepted", 
                                  "conversation-request", "conversation-request")), 
                    .Names = c("_id", "type"), class = "data.frame", 
                    row.names = c("list.1", "list.2", "list.3", "list.4", "list.5", "list.6"))
events$`_id` <- users$`_id`

> users
         _id
1 JTuXhdI4Ai
2 iGIeCEXyVE
3 6XFtOJh0bD
4 mNN986oQv9
5 9NI71KBMX9
6 x1jH7t0Cmy

> events
              _id                  type
list.1 JTuXhdI4Ai  conversation-request
list.2 iGIeCEXyVE conversation-accepted
list.3 6XFtOJh0bD  conversation-request
list.4 mNN986oQv9 conversation-accepted
list.5 9NI71KBMX9  conversation-request
list.6 x1jH7t0Cmy  conversation-request
```

We can use the same approach I suggested before, just enhance it a bit.

First we loop over `unique(events$type)` to store a `table()` of every type of event per id in a list:

```
test <- lapply(unique(events$type), function(x) table(events$`_id`, events$type == x))
```

Then we store the specific type as the name of the respective table in the list:

```
names(test) <- unique(events$type)
```

Now we use a simple `for`-loop to `match()` the `user$_id` with the `rownames` of the table and store the information in a new variable with the name of the event type:

```
for(i in names(test)){
  users[, i] <- test[[i]][, 2][match(users$`_id`, rownames(test[[i]]))]
}
```

Result:

```
> users
         _id conversation-request conversation-accepted
1 JTuXhdI4Ai                    1                     0
2 iGIeCEXyVE                    0                     1
3 6XFtOJh0bD                    1                     0
4 mNN986oQv9                    0                     1
5 9NI71KBMX9                    1                     0
6 x1jH7t0Cmy                    1                     0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the effort - I really like the approach - but this isn't quite the situation I am in because there are several values listed under `type`.  I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Instead of providing any `type`, I would advise you to `dput()` the `head()` of both dataframes.

Comment: I have added reduced versions of the data frames (columns with confidential data have been removed).

Comment: I've revised the answer, check it out.

Comment: This is so close!  It results in all NA values, unfortunately for all of the new columns; any idea why that might be?

Comment: `NA` will be generated for `id`s which do not overlap between `users` and `events`. Are you sure the overlap is 100%? You can test this with `all(unique(users[, "_id"]) %in% unique(events[, "_id"]))` and the reverse `all(unique(events[, "_id"]) %in% unique(users[, "_id"]))`

Comment: `all(unique(events[, "_id"]) %in% unique(users[, "_id"]))` results in `TRUE`; the inverse results in `FALSE`, so all user IDs are present in `events$_id`.